How to send SharePoint file as email attachment using logic app azure
I want to send the sharepoint file as a attachment in the email through the logic app, so please help me with the in detailed steps to do it. How to connect Azure Logic App to Sharepoint, which folders to be picked, how to create list or folders, which action to be taken in the logic app.
I've taken the action as a "When an item is created or modified" in that it is asking me for the Site Address & the List Name, but I'm not getting what should I write in those above two fields. And how to create the lists in the sharepoint. So please help me with this.

Hi! I recommend that you do some research on Google and specifically YouTube, sending emails with Logic Apps using files from SPO is about as close to hello-world as this gets. If you encounter some specific problem that you cannot Google or test your way out of, do not hesitate to come back with that and refine your question but I do not think it is fair for you to ask that people reproduce for you content that is very well developed. An example: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=G8KVS19vHMw - the example is for Flow but its close enough for a start.

I do agree with @KonTheCat, but if you are looking for an answer, I posted it below Priti Bogawat.

I do agree with @KonTheCat, but if you want to send file as attachment you can use below design:

Then next step :

Output:


